# Created HTML with charset=ISO-8859-1 is not displayed correctly

Tags: php, html

I have a variable containing special characters like `"é,ç"`:

```
$text='<HEAD><TITLE>'.$titre_test.'</TITLE><meta http-equiv="content-type"     
content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" /></HEAD><BODY>
<B>'.$titre_test.'<BR>   <BR>Sous La voix<BR><BR><HR>test n ('.$id_test.')
<BR><BR><BR><HR>Questions:<BR><bR>'.$Quistion_test.'';

file_put_contents('output.html', $text);
```

The text in *output.html* is not displayed correctly like this `"a Ã©tÃ© "programmÃ©e"`. But when I transfer the generated code to another old html file by selecting the code and pasting it into an old html page, it works. I guess the problem is somehow related to `charset=ISO-8859-1`. Any suggestions?

Comment: What's preventing you from using utf-8 as the charset?

Comment: Just because you *say* the content is encoded in ISO-8859-1 does not mean it is *actually* encoded that way.  If you have a mismatch then the content may be displayed in an unexpected manner -- exactly as you observe.

Comment: it work withe utf-8  but i am not sure to add this code $Quistion_test = str_replace("\'", "'",$Quistion_test, $Quistion_test); to fix "\ '"